# How can I add javascript variable to html tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function whose name is rendered which get two params: the container is a `<select>` in HTML and items just is my student array of an object which contains information of each student and it has 'class' property.

My idea is to create an `<opgroup>` tag in string and then pass it to HTML through `.innerHTML`. The problem is that I want to create a new `<optgroup>` relatively to student's class to separate each class, but I have no idea of passing `object.class`'s value to the `<optgroup>` label. Can you show me the way to pass a JavaScript variable to this `<optgroup id="optgroup-class"></optgroup>` string in a js file?

```
function render(container, items) {

    var htmlItems = items.map(function (item) {
        return '<option id="std-option">' + item.name + '</option>';
    });

    htmlItems.unshift('<optgroup id="optgroup-class"></optgroup>'); //add optgroup to the first index of htmlItems

    var html = htmlItems.join(''); //join all the <stringArray> to just one html tag string
    container.innerHTML = html; //get that <stringArray> to .student-list-container select in html
}
```

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding what you are wanting to achieve, could you perhaps rephrase it?

Comment: Does this work `htmlItems.unshift('<optgroup id="optgroup-class">'); htmlItems.push('</optgroup>');`?  You have to insert your items inside the optgroup element, but you close it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

> El método unshift() agrega uno o más elementos al inicio del array, y
>   devuelve la nueva longitud del array. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/unshift)

so, you are add `<optgroup id="optgroup-class"></optgroup>` at index 0

```
// [ '<optgroup id="optgroup-class"></optgroup>', '<option id="std-option"> name1 </option>', '<option id="std-option"> name1 </option>' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.

```js
function render(container, items) {
  let html = '';

  items.forEach(e => {
    html += `<optgroup label="${e.name}">`;
    e.options.forEach(o => {
      html += `<option value="${o.name}">${o.name}</option>`;
    });
    html += `</optgroup>`;
  });

  container.innerHTML = html;
}

let list = [{
  name: 'Swedish Cars',
  options: [{
      name: 'Volvo'
    },
    {
      name: 'Saab'
    }
  ]
}, {
  name: 'German Cars',
  options: [{
      name: 'Mercedes'
    },
    {
      name: 'Audi'
    }
  ]
}];

render(document.getElementById('my-select'), list);
```

```html
<select id="my-select"></select>
```

Comment: @KhaiPark.Nguyen please feel free to accept the answer. Accepting the answer can help other with similar issues